# Splitting large files by rows in GCP

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-compute-engine, google-app-engine-python

I have some very large files in GCP that I'd like to split down before copying across to AWS to be processed by a lambda.

Files can be as big as 50GB with millions of rows. I'm trying to split them to, say, 100k rows for the lambda to process.

As far as I'm aware, there's nothing in gsutils that can do this.

I've tried writing a file splitter as both a Cloud Function and deployed in App Engine but I've hit memory issues in testing. I went up to an F4 instance but that was still insufficient memory. This was the error I got processing only a 500mb file:

```
Exceeded hard memory limit of 1024 MB with 1787 MB after servicing 0 requests total. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml
```

This was the code deployed to App Engine to do the file splitting:

```
@app.route('/')
def run():
    LOGGER.info(f"Request received with the following arguments: {request.args}")

    # Request args
    bucket_name = request.args.get('bucket_name')
    file_location = request.args.get('file_location')
    chunk_size = int(request.args.get('chunk_size', 100000))

    LOGGER.info(f"Getting files in bucket: [{bucket_name}] with prefix: [{file_location}]")
    storage_client = storage.Client()

    for blob in storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name, prefix=file_location):
        blob_name = str(blob.name)
        if "json" in blob_name:
            LOGGER.info(f"Found blob: [{blob_name}]")
            blob_split = blob_name.split("/")
            file_name = blob_split[-1]

            bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
            LOGGER.info(f"Downloading file: [{file_name}]")
            download_blob = bucket.get_blob(blob_name)
            downloaded_blob_string = download_blob.download_as_string()
            downloaded_json_data = downloaded_blob_string.decode("utf-8").splitlines()
            LOGGER.info(f"Got blob: [{file_name}]")
            file_count = len(downloaded_json_data)
            LOGGER.info(f"Blob [{file_name}] has {file_count} rows")

            for file_number in range(0, file_count - 1, chunk_size):
                range_min = file_number
                range_max = file_number + chunk_size - 1
                if range_max > file_count:
                    range_max = file_count - 1
                LOGGER.info(f"Generating file for rows: {range_min+1} - {range_max+1}")
                split_file = "\n".join(downloaded_json_data[range_min:range_max+1]).encode("utf-8")
                LOGGER.info(f"Attempting upload of file for rows: {range_min+1} - {range_max+1}")
                upload_blob = bucket.blob(f"{file_location}split/{file_name}_split_{range_min+1}-{range_max+1}")
                upload_blob.upload_from_string(split_file)
                LOGGER.info(f"Upload complete for rows: {range_min+1} - {range_max+1}")
            LOGGER.info(f"Successfully split file: {file_name}")
    LOGGER.info(f"Completed all file splits for {file_location}")
    return "success"
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? What other alternatives do I have?

I want to automate this file splitting process which we have to do a couple of times in a month. Is my best bet to spin up a GCE instance each time so that I can just run the following:

```
 split -l 100000 file.json
```

Then shut it down after splitting is completed?

Comment: The cheapest will be to use a compute engine; The most scalable solution is to use Dataflow (but require a ramp up in the Beam programming language model)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere how would you do it in Dataflow? I thought it wasn't possible to control the number of lines/files outputted in Dataflow

Comment: Another option is stream or range over the Cloud Storage objects so that your e.g. Cloud Function(s) are able to deal with constraint-sized chunks. The Cloud Storage API supports both. In Python there are several alternatives including [`download_as_bytes`](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html?highlight=download_as_bytes#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.download_as_bytes).  I suspect you could parallelize this too this way. From an efficiency perspective, it may better to use a language other than Python.

Comment: You specifically asked for Lambda but, Google Cloud Functions (perhaps Cloud Run etc.) provide comparable functionality and would give you the ability to potentially reduce the network haul of large files if (pre)processing them locally on GCP could further reduce transit.

Comment: Using Cloud Functions to process Cloud Storage objects is a near perfect use case of Cloud Functions particularly when Functions are triggered by Cloud Storage events. There are myriad examples of Cloud Functions being used to zip, audit, thumbnail etc. etc. Cloud Storage objects and I suspect Google doesn't provide this functionality as part of GCS because it's relatively painless to publish Cloud Functions.

Comment: @DazWilkin unfortunately I don't have a choice with the lambda, that bit is out of my control

Comment: @csukcl, I just spent 2 hours to dirty cheat on Dataflow and yes, you create file of the number of line that you want. But it's not very efficient and you have to build sequential code in a distributed-design system. Not really  nice!

Comment: As an idea - to load into BigQuery with some metadata, then run a few queries to save mutually exclusive set of rows into a GCS bucket as manageable files/objects, and then push them into S3?

Comment: I am pretty sure your problem (a split of a huge file) can be solved by cloud function... but that should not be a single cloud function, probably a couple of them working together - one for coordination, and one to actual work...I guess

Answer (score 0):

For the **exceeded hard memory limit** error, you can use App Engine Flex and set your [custom machine resources](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/reference/app-yaml#resource-settings).
For this you will deploy an App Engine Flex application with the specific hardware that your instances will have in the resources section of your app.yaml.

But the best way is to spin up a GCE instance in the same region as your GCS bucket, download your object to that instance (which should be pretty fast, given that it's only a few dozen gigabytes), decompress the object (which will be slower), break that large file into a bunch of smaller ones (the linux split command is useful for this), and then upload the objects back up to GCS.